# C++: reading large pgm file with ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, pgm

I want to load a 16-bit binary PGM image with a size of 4096x4096 pixels using std::ifstream. The problem is that I can only load smaller files, eg. 512x512. If I try to load the "large" one the data I get is always 0 for every pixel.

Example Code:

```
int size = width*height;
unsigned short* data = new unsigned short[size];

// Read the terrain data
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    file >> data[i];
}
```

If I set size manually to a lower value, this seems to work. Any idea?

Thx Tim

Comment: Presumably this is binary data.  Read it as binary with `fstream.read()`.  Op>> likely fails early on and you don't know it.

Comment: Duck has a point, `operator >>` should not be used to extract binary data.

Comment: Ok, but `fstream.read()` reads chars as far as I know.

Comment: Then you should use `reinterpret_cast<char*>` for the data.

Comment: `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof data);`

Comment: OMG, thx a lot. This works as expected.

Comment: @TimV Great, I'll add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator >>` should not be used for binary extraction operations. Instead, by using `read` the file will simply input the bytes:

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof data);
```